# TFS automatically associate other work item which is not provided by ID

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfs-2015

I have two tasks under one user story i.e.

- User Story ID 1234

  - Task Id 5678 Status Active
  - Task Id 91011 Status Active
  - Task Id 121314 Status Closed

When check-in code to TFS, I am adding task ID 5678 to be associated with my change set but it is also associating task 121314 with same check in which has status closed.

after successful check in, i can see that my change-set is associated with Task ID 5678 & 121314.

Any thoughts?
Regards,

Comment: I've tested with TFS 2015.4.1 (14.114.27412.0) and VS 2015, but couldn't reproduce your issue. Could you please check whether task 5678 has any relationship with task 121314? Also, please try to create new tasks to check whether you can reproduce this issue with new tasks.

Comment: Thanks sir, both tasks are not associated to each other and still i can see that when i check in code it is associating to other task as well.

Comment: Could you test this in other team project to check the result?